# Colab: cache dataset on TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tpu

I'd like to setup something similar to [the following colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F8txK1JLXKtAkcvSRQz2o7NSTNoksuU2). I've got a 100MB single TFRecord and I'd like to train it using TPU.

My training input function is the following:

```
def train_input_fn(batch_size=1024):
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TRAIN_RECORD)
  dataset = dataset.cache()
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
  return dataset
```

From my understanding, when using the TPU the dataset cannot reside on the machine hard disk, that's why I added `dataset.cache()`. But I'm still getting

> UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: 'train.tfrecord')

Answer (score 2):

TPUs require google cloud storage.  local storage is not supported.

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#cannot_use_local_filesystem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error appears on this row `dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TRAIN_RECORD)` which works with local fs. I think you should load data outside your training function as it's done in the notebook.

Comment: But isn't loading a TFRecord can only be done inside the training function? I tried moving the first two lines outside of the function and got `local variable 'dataset' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: Just use different variables for that, e.g. `data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(TRAIN_RECORD)` and in the function `dataset = data.cache() ...`.

Comment: I'm still getting `File system scheme '[local]' not implemented...`. Also when `cache()`ing outside of the input function.

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace or a notebook?

Comment: p.s. The problem I think is that `tf` postpones real execution of these commands until you run the whole pipeline. You should load your data before running the `tf` pipeline.

Comment: [Here it is](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BkncIczMmGMgS_JmhuKTDDHKW-J_l5U-) (under "TPU test" section), thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184921/discussion-between-galah92-and-mikhail-berlinkov).

Comment: I take the reason is, as per @ChrisFregly's answer above "TPUs require google cloud storage. local storage is not supported.".